# Adding User to Organization Unit and Group using Google Directory API

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api

I am successful to create new user account using Google Directory API in .Net platform, but now I need to add that created user to Organization Unit and Group. I see the API details in this link to add the user to Organization Unit but any example showing insertion to Organization Unit would be greatly appreciated.

**Updated with working code:** Below is the code to create new user account using Directory API:

```
String serviceAccountEmail = ".........@developer.gserviceaccount.com";
                X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\key.p12", "secret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
                ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
                {
                    Scopes = new[]
                        {
                          DirectoryService.Scope.AdminDirectoryUser
                        },
                    User = "test@example.com",

                }.FromCertificate(certificate));

                var ser = new DirectoryService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = "Google Account",
                });
                try
                {                           
                    var user = new Google.Apis.Admin.Directory.directory_v1.Data.User()
                    {
                        Name = new Google.Apis.Admin.Directory.directory_v1.Data.UserName()
                        {

                            GivenName = FirstName.Text,
                            FamilyName = LastName.Text
                        },
                        Password = password
                    };

                    User newUser = new User();
                    UserName newUserName = new UserName();
                    newUser.PrimaryEmail = Email.Text;
                    newUserName.GivenName = FirstName_txt.Text;
                    newUserName.FamilyName = LastName_txt.Text;
                    newUser.Name = newUserName;
                    newUser.Password = password;

                 //Adding User to OU:
                    newUser.OrgUnitPath = "/Employee";
                    User results = ser.Users.Insert(newUser).Execute();

                //Adding User to Group:
                   Member newMember = new Member();
                   newMember.Email = Email.Text;
                   newMember.Role = "MEMBER";
                   newMember.Kind = "admin#directory#member";
                   api.Members.Insert(newMember, "Employee@example.com").Execute();
```

Any idea how to insert the created user in Organization Unit and Group using Directory API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To insert the new user into a Organization Unit just set the OU path when you create the user.

```
    User newUser = new User();
    UserName newUserName = new UserName();
    newUser.PrimaryEmail = Email.Text;
    newUserName.GivenName = FirstName_txt.Text;
    newUserName.FamilyName = LastName_txt.Text;
    newUser.Name = newUserName;
    newUser.Password = password;
    **newUser.OrgUnitPath ="\My\Organization\Unit\path\";**
    User results = ser.Users.Insert(newUser).Execute();
```

Now your user has been added to the OU path.

To add a member into a group see the following code.

```
    Member newMember = new Member();
    newMember.Email = userKey;//email of the user that you want to add
    newMember.Role = "MEMBER";
    newMember.Type = "USER";
    newMember.Kind = "admin#directory#member";

    ser.Members.Insert(newMember, "MyDestinationGroup@mydomain").Execute();
```

that's it.
Note: you must review the scopes for the correct permissions.
Hope this help you.

Comment: Hello Rodrigo, As you said I did code to insert user in OU and Group. Inserting user in OU is working but while inserting user in Group I get error: "Unauthorized client or Scope in request": Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponseException: Error:"unauthorized_client", Description:"Unauthorized client or scope in request.", Uri:""
I am including these scopes:  AdminDirectoryUser, AdminDirectoryOrgunit, AdminDirectoryGroup,  AdminDirectoryGroupMember  .

Any idea what I am missing, any scope or anything to check on Google Admin side?

Comment: It works fine with just these scopes (AdminDirectoryUser, AdminDirectoryGroup). You must add them in your code and must be declared on  API Client access administration too. 
on your domain admin console, go to security/advanced config/Managing Client Access API.   you can declare required scopes there. Must have administrator rights to access.